# image is not getting displayed on the web page .instead the text "loading..." is being displayed

Tags: php, html

my image is saved in a file ....and i have saved its path in the database....when i am fetching the image path from the database and trying to display it on  a given position on the web page it is simply not getting displayed instead a text "loading..." is appearing there

furthermore the inspect element is displaying the image path clearly, here it is

```
'<img id="image" alt="mgm axis" title="mgm axis" src="polybazaar_files/images/1.jpg"  style="display: block;"></img>'
```

now part of my code is here

```
while( $result=mysqli_fetch_array($runquery))  
{$GLOBALS['image']=$result['image'];}

<img src="<?php echo $image;  ?>" title="<?php echo $prodname;  ?>" alt="<?php echo $prodname;  ?>" id="image" />
```

where on a different page    `echo'<img src="'.($result['image']).'" />';` worked for the same image on the database....

i tried the suggestion mentioned here [Displaying an image using a php variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563639/displaying-an-image-using-a-php-variable)  and also tried suggestion mentioned  at other places  but none of them work

also my page has lot of java script in between ......are they creating problem?

any valuable and informative reasons or solutions will be appreciated ....thanks

Comment: I realize this is beside the point, but your closing img tag does nothing `</img>` since `<img>` is a singleton (void element, in other words: no opening or closing tag). See this for more info: http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/html-void-elements.htm The only exception to this is if you're writing in XHTML where the trailing slash would be required `<img/>`

Comment: How is the directory for your website structured?

Comment: @drmarvelous i have not saved the image as BLOB but instead i have saved the file path    do that needed to be encoded .... how?

Comment: @user3151681 I have done this before by saving the path as a VARCHAR, to which I added a limiting length of 1000 to (the links are populated by my website and would probably never exceed 100, however I added space in case someone decided to change this down the road)

Comment: @ctwheels the codes containing <img>....</img>    is not written by me  but is being shown by INSPECT ELEMENT. i am writing my cores in NetBeans .php file

Comment: @ctwheels i too have saved the path as a varchar , length 100 at which place you are referring  to add space

Comment: How is your directory structured? Where is the location of your HTML files?

Comment: on a single .php page HTML files are displayed using echo''; or by using include_once'';

Comment: I will reformulate my question... What is the structure of your directory (i.e. http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/qnx_4.25_docs/qnx4/user_guide/images/files.gif) and which folder is the location of the php file that you are experiencing issues with (i.e. with the image that I have linked `/boot`)

Comment: i am using windows7 ...i think the image you linked shoes linux file system structure...

Comment: Yes it is linux, I would like the equivalent of your directory for windows... If you can please add a table or list items to show what your directory looks like and where your files are placed, it would help in finding a solution.

Comment: well my is image in folders and sub folders of  D drive   here is its path D:\wamp\www\ecommerce\polybazaar_files\images

Comment: And where is your PHP file? The one that you've pasted the code from in the question

Comment: here it is D:\wamp\www\ecommerce\productdetails.php

Comment: @drmarvelous Your suggestion is ridiculous.  There is no need to store the image data in the database in this case, and even if you were, base64 encoding it adds 33% overhead as well as the processing time for encoding/decoding.  There's nothing wrong with BLOB, but that isn't what is needed here.

Comment: Yes I agree 100%, I had originally misread the question and thought he was loading the image from the table, and not just the files relative path.

Comment: @user3151681 Your question doesn't really make any sense.  You posted some HTML and you say your paths are correct, but you've put all your HTML in quotes.  If the paths are correct then why post anything about PHP?  And what's all this "loading..." text?  Where does it come from?  You need to greatly simplify your question.  First, actually verify that your image paths are correct... it doesn't sound like they are based on your last comment.  Actually go to the image paths and see if they load in your browser.  Then decide if the problem is server-side or client-side.

Comment: @drmarvelous Ah, got it.  Yes, this is a very confusing question.

Comment: I don't understand this "Part of my code" part... The first 2 lines are PHP and the last two are HTML with PHP to fill its attributes?

Comment: @user3151681 if you echo $image what is the path that shows up?

Comment: @brad......the CODE i have put IN QUOTES  are not mine but being shown by RIGHT CLICK->INSPECT ELEMENT. And i have shown it to clearify that  my file path is being send to the server...@ctwheels  I too guess it is a java script problem.... though not good at it ..i will try to fix it....thanks for your valuable comments and time....thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it fixed .....

actually the address at the top of my script

```
<base href="http://polybazaar.in/shop/" />
```

needed to be put inside the comment, since i am working on a local server....or the address  of a DEFAULT TARGET should be given if one wants its server request to be accessed from that URL.....

thanks all for their valuable comments